# Regex for japanese fullwidth characters

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I wrote this code in order to make user only can input number in text box.
However, I found the bug when user input japanese fullwidth characters. It'll not filter these characters out. How can I solve this problem?

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/i,'');
  }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of a Japenese fullwidth character that the regex does not replace? According to [my quick test](https://regex101.com/r/PmPIH3/1), the characters match just fine?

Comment: Or are you saying you want to the regex to **not** replace japanese characters??

Comment: As Tom Lord, I don't see this problem. Furthermore, I'd like to point out that the ignorecase flag (`i`) is useless in this case.

Comment: I've written an [online demo](http://jsbin.com/wixufawavo/1/edit?html,js,output) and I definitively get `０１２３４５６７８９` removed. Is it possible that Japanese browsers make a transparent conversion to `0123456789`?

Comment: So, do you need `/[^0-9０-９]+/g`?

Comment: try adding `/iu`, it will activate the unicode mode